# How to make a dynamically generated SSIS package to show full descriptions of tasks?

Tags: ssis, containers, task

I have generated an SSIS package dynamically, many of the task names are large. When I open the package in BIDS, the task containers are shrunk enough so that i cannot read the entire name of the task without having to manually expand them. This gets tedious if you're trying to visually understand the package members.

Is there a setting I can configure (programmatically as the task is dynamically generated) so that task container rects are defaulted to fit the entire name of the task??

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you generating them? Straight api calls or a third party library

Comment: Since I was ignorant, here's two links of what I found. [Extended properties](http://books.google.com/books?id=JhwR9HVEVooC&pg=PT239&lpg=PT239&dq=PackageVariableValue+ExtendedProperties&source=bl&ots=n4zxYsmXfA&sig=S9HUYFkb90yd1L9pfOeXPg4FVCE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rEonT5OrLYqEsALDotD3Ag&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=PackageVariableValue%20ExtendedProperties&f=false) [Adding Annotations](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/sqlintegrationservices/thread/bebb1068-4ef6-4d60-9364-b194e172f440?prof=required) It seems it's going to be a matter of generating correct XML and assigning to ExtendedProps

Comment: I'm using straight API calls to the DTS wrapper classes.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which version of SSIS, but the below examples are for 2005; it shouldn't be hard to adopt to later versions.

I don't think there's a property to auto-resize a task (not so for annotations).
One solution would be to alter the generated dtsx file, either programmatically or using an XSL transformation; if you open a dtsx file up, you'll see that your task has a `DTSID`, something like

```
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">My Task</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="DTSID">{0B86AAA3-1F48-4F35-B18B-3B3CA8CB1305}</DTS:Property>
```

Further up in the dtsx file, there's a section that controls the layout of that particular instance; it's contained within a `PackageVariable` section (called ExtendedProperties in later versions, I think), in a `ddscontrol` sub-section. Something like:

```
<DTS:PackageVariable>
...
&lt;ddscontrol width="3598" height="1164" noresize="0" nomove="0" &gt;
...
&lt;property name="LogicalObject" value="{0B86AAA3-1F48-4F35-B18B-3B3CA8CB1305}" vartype="8" /&gt;
...
&lt;/ddscontrol&gt;
...
</DTS:PackageVariable>
```

I snipped a lot out for clarity, but you can see the full text if you open any dtsx file in a text editor.  Obviously, the `LogicalObject` entry links to the earlier-found `DTSID`.

The piece you want is the `width` property contained in the `ddscontrol` node.  Changing this to a larger value would give you a wider control; I'm betting you could come up with a reasonable heuristic to generate the value based on your text string length.